# change java version while creating Swagger2 project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

Hi I am trying to generate a springboot project using java, by default in pom.xml java version 1.8 is being used I need to use java 11 how can I do that

conf file: **codegen_config.json**

```
{
     "artifactId" : "projectname",
     "groupId" : "com.example",
     "additionalProperties" :{
        "dateLibrary" : "java8"     //tried replacing it with java11 not working
     }
     ........
     ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration option does not imply that you have to use Java 8 for your project. It only determines the date library to use. There are four options:

- **joda**
  Joda (for legacy app only)
- **legacy**
  Legacy java.util.Date
- **java8-localdatetime**
  Java 8 using LocalDateTime (for legacy app only)
- **java8**
  Java 8 native JSR310 (preferred for jdk 1.8+)

Comment: what about java8 : true property?